# Encrypting an IV with XEX using a block cipher and XORing on the plaintext: Is this scheme valid?

Tags: encryption, initialization-vector, xor

I had an idea to make [XEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor%E2%80%93encrypt%E2%80%93xor) mode parallelizable at CPU level.

Let's suppose I take an IV, XOR with random data, encrypt, XOR again with another data, and XOR on the plaintext

Would this encipherment scheme be valid? Would it be secure?